# How do I copy data from production to the development server in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

appcfg.py download_data does not work with namespaces.

Moreover, using appcfg.py download_data does not work without explicitly specifying a kind which means that I need to manually specify kinds and download all kinds one by one, and then upload them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the docs that specifically talk about downloading/uploading all your data ?

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata#Python_Downloading_and_uploading_all_data

Note it says the --kind option is that an option.  You can get all of the data by omitting that option.

Comment: download_data doesn't work with namespaces. I need namespace support.

Comment: My bad, missed the namespace reference, there's an outstanding bug against namespace and download_data.  Namespaces seem to be a bit of an issue for a range of these sort of tasks.